# Lower bound on ODE (Gronwall)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Consider a well-defined first-order ODE

$$
\frac{du(t)}{dt} = F(t, u) + G(t),
$$
which has a unique continuous solution on $t\in[0,\infty)$

Suppose that

1. The solution $u(t)>0$, and $u(0)>0$.
2. $|F(t,u)| \leq f(t)\, u(t)$, where $f(t)>0$ is continuous and uniformly bounded.
3. $G(t)>C>0$ s continuous and uniformly bounded.

Now I want to compose a **positive lower bound** of solution $u(t)$, such that

$$
u(t)\geq \,?
$$

on $t\in[0,\infty)$.

---

Upper bound can be directly obtained by Gronwall's lemma. Here are some papers could help with the proof on lower bound: [1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2033951?seq=2#metadata_info_tab_contents) [2](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2034563.pdf)

Comment: Do you mean Grönwall's inequality? The name is sometimes spelled Gronwall in american publications, but i never heard of anyone named Grownwall.

Comment: I edited your question changing "Gronwall's inequality" to "Gronwall's lemma". Anyways, you question has a simple answer: just define $v(t)=u(T-t)$.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen Yes. Sorry I have difficulty memorizing names.

Comment: @JohnB Thanks, I fixed my question ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an extremely simplistic lower bound using integrating factors.

Your equation implies

$$ u'(t) \geq G(t) - f(t) u(t) $$

If you write $h(t) = \exp \int_0^t f(s) ds$ then you have

$$ (h(t) u(t))' \geq G(t) h(t) $$

and so you have

$$ h(t) u(t) \geq u(0) + \int_0^t G(s) h(s) ~ds $$

or

$$ u(t) \geq \frac{1}{h(t)} u(0) + \int_0^t \frac{h(s)}{h(t)} G(s) ~ds $$

Comment: Is it possible to extend this to a non-linear case? That is, $|F(t,u)| \leq f(t)\, \beta(u(t))$, where $\beta$ is continuous positive increasing function.

Comment: e.g., let's say $\beta(u(t)) = u^p(t)$ for some $0<p<1$

Comment: @NathanExplosion: yes you can extend to to non-linear cases; but it really depends on exactly what you want. For example, notice that by concavity you have that if $f(t)$ is uniformly bounded in $t$, that $$ f(t) u^p(t) \leq M u^p(t) \leq C_0 + M_0 u(t) $$ when $p \in (0,1)$. Then you can apply the same estimate as above. Whether this is useful for you depends on what you want to apply this to.

Comment: But then we need to ensure that $G(t) - C_0\geq 0$, so that the lower bound is positive.

Comment: The mapping $u \mapsto M u^p$ is concave and passes through the origin. For any $\epsilon > 0$ you can find a tangent line to its graph that has $y$ intercept equal to $\epsilon$, and the graph lies below the tangent line. In particular, you can choose $0 < C_0 < C$ to your liking.